# AlarmManager and Time Issue

Tags: java, android

im working on my android app. i need to make an Alarm manager, it should notify every day at some hour.

But the problem its for example: if now is 16:00HR and i set these variables at 14:00HR it should sound the day after but when i run my app, the alarm notify at start (because now are 16:00 and it was setted at 14:00).

My setted intents, i do this before call the alarm method

```
Intent intAlarmaManual = new Intent( getActivity(), AlarmaManualBroad.class );
pdIntAlarmaManual = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( getActivity(), 0, intAlarmaManual, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );
```

My Method

```
private void setearAlarmaManual()
{
        // Variables for testing
        hr = 14;    
        min = 00;

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE );

        /** Set alarm by user selections **/
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis( System.currentTimeMillis() );
        calendar.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hr );
        calendar.set( Calendar.MINUTE,      min );

        manager.setInexactRepeating( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pdIntAlarmaManual );

        Toast.makeText( getActivity(), "Alarm OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}
```

My Receiver

```
  public class AlarmaManualBroad extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
         @Override
         public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
         {
              // Toast, notifys, etc.
         }
    }
```

Hope u can help me. ^^

Comment: Set the first alarm time to one day after. That is `calendar.setTimeInMillis( System.currentTimeMillis() + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS );`

Comment: Its works but... how exactly this works ? i can use this for an alarm every day ? many thanks btw !

Comment: If the alarm time is earlier than current time, the first alarm will be triggered immediately. You can use this for an alarm every day.